UnsatisfiedLinkError When Loading Native Library After Dynamic Feature Module Install
I'm developing an Android app using Dynamic Feature Modules (DFM). After installing a DFM through the Play Store, I'm encountering an UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library not found error when trying to load a native library immediately after the module installation.
Here is the error log:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/~~lSAlrQ==/com.exsam.exam-C6Age1h-SyA8idiefe==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libExsampleJni.so" not found

Interestingly, if I restart the app after the DFM installation, the native library loads without any issues.
Steps I've Tried:

Using ReLinker:
ReLinker.loadLibrary(this, "ExsampleJni")


Using SplitInstallHelper:
SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(this, "ExsampleJni")


Using Absolute Path:
val libPath = "/data/app/~~lSAlrQ==/com.exsam.exam-C6Age1h-SyA8idiefe==/lib/arm64/libExsampleJni.so"
System.load(libPath)



Despite these attempts, the native library still fails to load immediately after the DFM installation.
Questions:

What is the best way to ensure the native library loads from the default path after a DFM installation?
How can I configure System.loadLibrary to reference the default library path?
Are there any additional tips or tricks to reliably load native libraries after a DFM install?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.
